# "Invalid AES Block Size" SJCL Decryption

Tags: javascript, python, encryption, rncryptor, sjcl

Trying to decrypt AES using [RNCryptor-js](https://github.com/RNCryptor/rncryptor-js) which uses SJCL. After logging all the steps on each end, (other end is [RNCryptor-python](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-python)) the keys, salts, HMAC hashes, everything matches up. But when I get to the final step:

```
var aes = new sjcl.cipher.aes(encryption_key);
sjcl.beware["CBC mode is dangerous because it doesn't protect message integrity."]()
var decrypted = aes.decrypt(ciphertext, iv);
```

I get the error:

```
 sjcl.exception.invalid {toString: function, message: "invalid aes block size"}
```

Here is the full code:

PBKDF2:

```
this.KeyForPassword = function(password, salt) {

  var hmacSHA256 = function (password) {
      var hasher = new sjcl.misc.hmac(password, sjcl.hash.sha256);
      this.encrypt = function () {
          return hasher.encrypt.apply(hasher, arguments);
      };
  };
  return sjcl.misc.pbkdf2(password, salt, 10000, 32 * 8, hmacSHA256);
};
```

Decryption (takes a hex input):

```
this.decrypt = function(password, message, options) {

  message = sjcl.codec.hex.toBits(message);

  options = options || {};

  var version = sjcl.bitArray.extract(message, 0 * 8, 8);
  var options = sjcl.bitArray.extract(message, 1 * 8, 8);

  var encryption_salt = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, 2 * 8, 10 * 8);
  var encryption_key = _this.KeyForPassword(password, encryption_salt, "decryption");

  var hmac_salt = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, 10 * 8, 18 * 8);
  var hmac_key = _this.KeyForPassword(password, hmac_salt, "decryption");

  var iv = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, 18 * 8, 34 * 8);

  var ciphertext_end = sjcl.bitArray.bitLength(message) - (32 * 8);
  var ciphertext = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, 34 * 8, ciphertext_end);

  var hmac = sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, ciphertext_end);
  var expected_hmac = new sjcl.misc.hmac(hmac_key).encrypt(sjcl.bitArray.bitSlice(message, 0, ciphertext_end));

  if (! sjcl.bitArray.equal(hmac, expected_hmac)) {
    throw new sjcl.exception.corrupt("HMAC mismatch or bad password.");
  }

  var aes = new sjcl.cipher.aes(encryption_key);
  sjcl.beware["CBC mode is dangerous because it doesn't protect message integrity."]()
  var decrypted = aes.decrypt(ciphertext, iv);

  return decrypted;
}
```

The error is thrown on the second to last statement where `decrypted` is defined.

I looked at the sjcl exception and it looks like it's looking for an input of length 4, which I'm guessing is a WordArray. I'm just lost as to how to get a valid input. Like I said, the ciphertext, iv, hmac tag, salts are all being sliced properly on the javascript end. Might just be an encoding problem.

This error also seems to only be happening on json (format: '{"key":"value"}'), when I tried something like "Hello, world" I got back a 4 word array with no errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you are using JSON, if you set your code to output ciphertext.length what is it saying that length is?

Comment: @WDS, `ciphertext.length` returned various lengths for different json. For a shorter one I got 16, a longer one: 24, an even longer one: 36.

Comment: If I use Crypto-JS instead to do the last decryption step I get no error but I do get an empty WordArray.

Comment: I'm a little bit out of my element, but it seems possible that the Encrypt and Decrypt functions can handle only 1 block at a time and that you need to manually split your cipher text into individual blocks, split each block into 4 words, and hand them into the function 4 words at a time.  .NET has methods to process any length of cipher text in a single set of commands, but I'm guessing you need to write your own.  As a test, try BitSlice-ing your cipher text down to 128 bits and pass it into the decrypt function.  See if that decrypts to part of the plain text.

Comment: Good idea. Tried the split and I got back a word array but I can't encode it for some reason. Neither CryptoJS nor sjcl Utf8 stringification seems to work

Comment: Sorry to say I am stumped at this point.  If you want to post the whole program for both sides, I would be happy to tinker with them and try to find the issue.  But unfortunately at the moment I am out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for offering to help! Here is the [python](http://pastebin.com/ZJvzkvBF) and the [javascript](http://pastebin.com/dYTB6GXV)

Comment: Man, I am sorry to say I am having even worse luck than you.  Python side worked like a charm, but I cannot get JavaScript to quit throwing an exception "Crypto.Js is undefined" no matter what I do.

Comment: Dang. Did you see the html in the javascript with the links to the libraries? Thanks again, man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var decrypted = aes.decrypt(ciphertext, iv);
```

should be

```
 var decrypted = sjcl.mode.cbc.decrypt(aes, ciphertext, iv);
```

I was also having trouble with padding happening in `cbc.js` [(link to source)](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/cbc.js#L104) and it turned out that I hadn't included `bitArray.js` [(link)](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/bitArray.js#L184) which includes an important `xor` function (not to confused with the simple `^` operator).

So: **include bitArray.js**

The output should also be encoded:

```
return sjcl.codec.utf8String.fromBits(decrypted);
```

Comment: For the people reading this: don't forget that the parameters must be in bits: var kbits = sjcl.codec.arrayBuffer.toBits(new Uint8Array(key).buffer);
                            var aes = new sjcl.cipher.aes(kbits); var plainBinary = sjcl.mode.cbc.decrypt(aes, sjcl.codec.arrayBuffer.toBits(encryptedBinary.buffer), sjcl.codec.arrayBuffer.toBits(iv.buffer));